# Overriding JSX attributes with JSX spread attributes

Tags: reactjs, jsx, spread-syntax

JSX does not allow an attribute to be specified more than once.

F.ex.

```
<Component prop1="a" prop1="b" />        /* <- This is not allowed */
```

I was wondering what happens if an attribute is specified once explicitly but, additionally, another spread attribute that contains the same attribute is passed to the component:

```
<Component prop1="a" {...obj} />         /* where obj contains an attribute called "prop1" */
```

Will the order of attributes be important? E.g. will the second attribute override the first one?

Comment: why not try it? and yes, later attributes overwrite earlier ones

Comment: @AndyRay That's wrong! Firstly defined attribute will be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prop that comes 2nd will override the first.

In this case `prop1` will be `"b"`.

ex:

```
const obj = {prop1: 'b' };
return (<Component prop1="a" {...obj} />);
```

This follows how object spreading works.

[MDN Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

ex:

```
const a = { prop1: 'a' };
const b = { prop1: 'b' };
const c = { ...a, ...b };
```

Object `c` will have a `prop1` of `"b"` because object `b` was spread in 2nd.

ex: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prop-tester-tsted)

edit: For additional proof and docs from react: [Spread attributes in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar This is using react and object spread. I don't think the first will ever take precedence even with straight html. See the code sandbox for proof.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar That isn't true. His example matches the fist sandbox that I made and you forked. Yours does not match his example of having obj have an attribute called prop1.

Comment: He got scared. Thanks for the support though